# What is this animation and how to create it?

Tags: animation, web, svg

I visited [lofavor](http://budsjettesten.lofavor.no/) website and I saw a very cute animation there. Can someone tell me what is this animation? It's obvious that it's not flash or JavaScript animation. The element is SVG. But how can I create an animation like that with SVG?

It is a little complicated animation than simple Rotate, Translation or Scaling. Please give me any tip or keyword to have a research on this. Do I have to code all the transitions or is there any WYSIWYG way to do this?

Comment: Why down vote? Just tell me what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's SVG Transform animation and yes you have to code it. For more information you can check [`SVG Transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/transform).

If you check the DOM element, which I think you did, you would see `g` elements with `transform` attribute and a matrix which defines the `Rotation`, `Translation` or `Scale`.

[image: SVG Animation]

There is also a masking technique for that red ribbon which rolls at first. A good start to work with SVG is [`SVG Essential`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002238) book.

Comment: thanks now i know what to look for